# Splitting the string, memorizing the delimiter and appending it as a space

Tags: java, string, algorithm, collections, split

Good day everyone,

I have a string that looks like this (Morse code):

```
....x.x.-..x.-..x---xx...x-x.-x-.-.x-.-x---x...-x.x.-.x..-.x.-..x---x.--
```

single "x" means that the letter is finishing at that point, double "x" means that it's the end of the whole word. I have a map with Morse code. I am splitting the string by "x", then comparing each encoded letter to values in my dictionary and appending the matching key to my StringBuilder, it works correctly but I want to keep spaces between the words instead of double xx.

My piece of code:

```
private static final Map<Character, String> morseCode;
    static {
        morseCode = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        morseCode.put('h', "....");
        morseCode.put('e', ".");
        morseCode.put('l', ".-..");
        morseCode.put('o', "---");
        morseCode.put('s', "...");
        morseCode.put('t', "-");
        morseCode.put('a', ".-");
        morseCode.put('c', "-.-.");
        morseCode.put('k', "-.-");
        morseCode.put('v', "...-");
        morseCode.put('r', ".-.");
        morseCode.put('f', "..-.");
        morseCode.put('w', ".--");
    }

String decodedMorseTable = "....x.x.-..x.-..x---xx...x-x.-x-.-.x-.-x---x...-x.x.-.x..-.x.-..x---x.--"
StringBuilder decodedText = new StringBuilder();
String[] splitLetters = decodedMorseTable.split("x");
    for(String letter: splitLetters) {
        for(Map.Entry<Character, String> entry: morseCode.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().equals(letter))
                decodedText.append(entry.getKey());
```

Output:

```
hellostackoverflow
```

Comment: Why not split on the xx's first to get words, then on x's within the words to get letters?

Comment: What do you mean with: *I want to keep spaces between the words instead of double xx*?

Comment: @NiVer in place of double xx* Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @AndyTurner I've tried in this way but it seems that I am splitting incorrectly, eventually it goes to check to my map with spaces in-between the letters and the output is not entirely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the input into separate words first (by `xx`). Then split each word as you did before:

```
String decodedMorseTable = "....x.x.-..x.-..x---xx...x-x.-x-.-.x-.-x---x...-x.x.-.x..-.x.-..x---x.--";
StringBuilder decodedText = new StringBuilder();
String[] words = decodedMorseTable.split("xx");
for (String word : words) {
    String[] splitLetters = word.split("x");
    for (String letter : splitLetters) {
        for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : morseCode.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(letter))
                decodedText.append(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    decodedText.append(" ");
 }
```

**Update**

If you modify your `morseCode` to have morse letters as keys and the characters as values then the code will look much simpler (avoiding 3rd loop):

```
private static final Map<String, Character> morseCode;
static {
    morseCode = new HashMap<>();
    morseCode.put("....", 'h');
    morseCode.put(".", 'e');
    morseCode.put("", ' ');
...   


String[] splitLetters = word.split("x");
for (String letter : splitLetters) {
    decodedText.append(morseCode.get(letter));
}
```

**Java 1.8+** solution:

```
Arrays.stream(decodedMorseTable.split("x"))
      .map(morseCode::get)
      .forEach(decodedText::append);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!
I've been trying to split it by double xx incorrectly, appending the space directly with a word and doing nothing about it.

Comment: Glad it helped! Check my updates to see how you can optimize your code.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to split on xx: `morseCode.put("", ' ');` would handle word breaks whilst only splitting on x.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your desired output looks like this:

```
hello stackoverflow
```

What you could try is get the index of all "xx"s with decodedMorseTable.indexOf("xx") first and insert a space in those locations afterwards. But remember to offset the inserted space by the number of spaces inserted before it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks for your hint! That's a good idea as well, I didn't want to dance around it too much, that's why I've been looking for a solution with "split" :)

Comment: I agree, the solution with split is much cleaner